# How should I handle the Uber surge confirmation url in iOS?

Tags: ios, uber-api

What I mean is that I have well received the Uber 409 conflict surge error JSON response:

```
{
   "meta": {
      "surge_confirmation": {
      "href": "https:\/\/api.uber.com\/v1\/surge-confirmations\/e100a670",
      "surge_confirmation_id": "e100a670"
      }
   },
   "errors":[
      {
         "status": 409,
         "code": "surge",
         "title": "Surge pricing is currently in effect for this product."
      }
   ]
}
```

So what I should do is that present the HTML5 page with the following url, right?

`"href": "https:\/\/api.uber.com\/v1\/surge-confirmations\/e100a670"`

And here comes my two questions:

1. I would like to present the page in my iOS UIWebView, but I don't know what to do to close the webview if user clicked `I ACCEPT HIGHER FEE` button of the HTML5 page since I don't know how to leverage the surge confirmation redirect url;
2. When loading the url in my OSX chrome, clicked the button and it redirected to next page; when loading the url in an UIWebView, clicking the button didn't trigger anything.

Many thanks.

Comment: have you worked on webhooks in iOS for Uber. can you provide some links regarding this?

Comment: @Hussain, I didnt use webhooks. What I am doing now is that I have created a webview for the surge confirmation page to present. Now when I click the 'Accept the surge' button on the HTML5 page, there is no response at all, I have set the surge confirmation url as `https://www.uber.com` since I don't know what it is used for.

Comment: So I wanna know what redirect url I should set to go further. Do you mean that I have to set both surge redirect url and webhook url to enable the surge confirmation mechanism?

Comment: no I didn't mean that. I was just asking about the webhooks have you worked on it?

Comment: No, I haven't figured the surge thing out so I am now focusing on that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, I figured that the surge confirmation id is added as a query param in the redirect url. So what you need to do is capture the redirect url (if you didn't register any, then you cannot capture the confirmation id string) and resolve it out.

Also I think if you don't register any redirect url, Uber would consider user has denied the surge price either the button was clicked or not. So if you wanna enable the surge confirmation you have to register one redirect url.

And the reason nothing happened after I clicked the button is that I didn't register a redirect url for the surge confirmation so it didn't jump anywhere else.

Comment: what format was your redirect uri in the uber developer console? I put `MyApp://surge/callback` and I'm getting an error: Surge Confirmation Redirect URI must be a valid URL. It's the same format as my Oauth callback url that I have registered with them...

Comment: @tylerSF have you fixed this? "MyApp://surge/callback" is this worked? or did you provide server url as we doing in OAuth 2 ?

Comment: @ramz yes, that is the format that worked. I think it was a validation bug on their end. "myappname://surge/callback" is what I have in the dev settings right now and it handles surge requests for my app